# How do I change my url to the post link id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to design a reddit/hacker news like website for my project. When I click on the url for a post, it's something like `www.website.com/links/4`. I need the url path to be like `www.website.com/item?id=1234`.

Not too sure where to start. Tried using slug but I didn't have any luck.

EDIT:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :links, except: :index do
resources :comments, only: [:create]
end
get '/comments' => 'comments#index'
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create] do
delete :destroy, on: :collection
end
get 'misc/about'
get 'users/new' 
root 'links#index'
end
```

Comment: You need to change the `routes` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string

Comment: Can you please add your routes in question ?

Comment: Add following in the question 1) content of `config/routes.rb` and 2) the `.html.erb` where you display the link.

Comment: I had a read through the query string and added the `'links:id', to: 'links@show'` . Do i need to add a link_to to the controller next?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some documentation about rails and routing to help get you started:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- https://richonrails.com/articles/understanding-rails-routing

First of all you have to check that you have something along this line in your route or add it:

```
get "/item", to: "method#controller"
```

You have to use a `get` route, if you use a `post` route your parameters will be passed via 'invisible' parameters. You will retrieve them in your controller all the same with an `item = params[:item]`

Then you will have to change the `link_to` in your article view for something like

```
<%= link_to "/item?id=" + item_id, "Link to item" %>
```